# Finding the next higher value in a column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, lookup

I have two columns, `A` and `B`. Column `B` has values which I need to look up in Column `A`. However, I don't need to find the exact corresponding value, I need the next higher value.

For example:

```
Column A    Column B   

   2           3
   4           4
   5           5
   7           6
   8           8
   9           9
```

So, for the value `5` in column `B`, I want to return `7` from column `A`.

I guess I probably need some form of lookup / index-match function but I haven't been able to write the formula myself.

Comment: Is your data always going to be sorted?

Comment: I think what you're looking for is the value in column A which is the next value greater than the value you're looking for.  If all the values are integers, and you can't sort, you could calculate B+1-A and look for the smallest value >= 0.

Comment: @Xalorous It's a little more complicated than that for an unsorted column `A`. Finding the smallest value using a lookup function or `MATCH()` ***requires*** the column to be sorted. It *can* be done, but it you need to use an array formula, the `SMALL()` function, and some trickery.

Comment: Hello all,  the columns can be sorted indeed, it is not a requirement for them to stay in the same order.

Answer (score 3):

### Sorted

The simplest formula is for the case where column `A` is sorted in ascending order:

[image: Worksheet Screenshot]

Enter the following formula in `C1` and ctrl-enter/copy-paste/fill-down/auto-fill into the rest of the table's column:

```dart
=INDEX(A:A,1+MATCH(B1,A:A,1))
```

**Explanation:**

The `1` as the third argument of `MATCH()` means that it finds the largest value that is less than or equal to the first argument. Adding `1` to that index results in the index of the next higher number. The `INDEX()` function then extracts the number.

Note that I have added an extra value at the end of column `A`. This is for the special case where there is no next higher value.

---

### Unsorted

For the case where column `A` is unsorted (also works if sorted), the formula is a little more complicated:

Array enter (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) the following formula in `C1` and copy-paste/fill-down into the rest of the table column (don't forget to remove the `{` and `}`):

```dart
{=SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$6>B1,$A$1:$A$6),1)}
```

**Explanation:**

The `SMALL(array,n)` function returns the nth smallest value of the array, ***ignoring boolean values***. As the default for the third argument of the `IF()` function is `FALSE`, only values greater than the value in column `B` are checked, resulting in the next higher value.

Note that a special terminating value for column `A` is not required, as a `#NUM!` error is the result if there are no values in column `A` greater than the value in column `B`.

---

Finally, as aventurin has pointed out, there is an alternate, similar formula which works irrespective of sorting (but with an important caveat).

For Excel 2016+:

```dart
=MINIFS($A$1:$A$6,$A$1:$A$6,">"&B1)
```

This works because the `MINIFS()` function filters out the values that don't match the criteria(s) before extracting the minimum value.

For earlier versions of Excel:

```dart
{=MIN(IF($A$1:$A$6>B1,$A$1:$A$6))}
```

This works for the same reason as the `SMALL()` function - it ignores boolean values generated by the `IF()` function.

**Caveat:**

Both the `=MINIFS()` and `{=MIN(IF())}` formulas won't work correctly if a zero can be the correct next higher value, as zero is also returned when there *is* no next higher value. (This is the same reason for adding an extra value at the end of column `A` for the first formula - that formula also returns a zero if there are no higher values.)

Comment: Does `MATCH()` return the cell address or the value?

Comment: @Xalorous - `MATCH()` returns a row number. `Index` returns a value from that row number.

Comment: @Xalorous `MATCH()` returns the 1-based index into the range of the second argument. That turns out to be the row number if the range is an entire column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use e.g. the array function `{=MIN(IF(A1:A6 > B1; A1:A6))}` or `{=MIN(IF(A1:A6 > B1; A1:A6; 1000))}` (with 1000 as fallback value).

It takes the minimum of all values from column A that are greater than the vaue from the current cell from column B (here `B1`). Therefore neither of the columns must be sorted.

With Excel >= 2016 you may also use the `MINIFS` function.

Note that array functions must be inserted by pressing `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`.